# How add the original direction pane to a custom map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gdirections

I have a custome map, and I need to add this panel to my map :

[image]

I was able to add the search bar thanks to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) tutorial :
[image]

Now, in the documentation, I did not find any examples other than customs ones : [Directions service (complex)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex).

**Therefore, how can I add the original direction pane to my map ?**

Answer (score 0):

The closes thing Google offers for searching for direction with orgin and direction is using [Places autocomplete and direction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions).